# Unity - Android - Determining if "Opt out of Ads Personalization" is enabled?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ads

In Unity, for Android devices, how do I determine if "Opt out of Ads Personalization" under Google settings is set to true?

For Unity IOS you can use Device.advertisingTrackingEnabled but under UnityEngine.Android I can't find anything similar :/